# Terraform AWS API Gateway policy reference own ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, devops

I'm using Terraform to configure a number (hundreds, actually) of things on AWS, and my `applies` are idempotent save one annoying example.

I am creating a `aws_api_gateway_rest_api` with the following configuration:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "my_gateway" {
  name        = "my_gateway"
  description = "my_gateway description"

  tags = {
    Client      = var.client_name
    Environment = var.environment_name
  }

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": [
              "execute-api:/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
POLICY
}
```

An `apply` or `plan` always shows this change:

```
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_gateway will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "my_gateway" {
        api_key_source           = "HEADER"
        ... snip ...
        name                     = "my-gateway"
      ~ policy                   = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              ~ Statement = [
                  ~ {
                        Action    = "execute-api:Invoke"
                        Effect    = "Allow"
                        Principal = "*"
                      ~ Resource  = "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:123456789:placeholder/*" -> [
                          + "execute-api:/*",
                        ]
                    },
                ]
                Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
```

In words, the policy includes the ARN shorthand `"execute-api:/*"` but this is expanded to the real ARN of the `aws_api_gateway_rest_api` at runtime. Because the Terraform manifest doesn't match exactly what is on AWS the plan is "dirty".

Is there either/or:

- some way I can attach the policy separately with a policy attachment later, so I can wait for the ARN to be resolved?
- is there some way to refer to my own ARN?

Comment: That ARN does not seem to match the resource provided. It seems like an ARN for another api gateway.

Comment: A "resource-based policy" (which an API gateway policy is) should not usually have a `Resource` argument because its resource is implied to be the object that the policy is attached to -- in this case, the API gateway REST API you're writing it inside. The `Resource` argument is intended for use in identity-based policies only. For more information, see [Identity-Based Policies and Resource-Based Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html).

Comment: Thank you Martin, if you added this as an answer I could at least accept it. Otherwise, I will do so in a couple of days, I literally dropped `Resource` from the policy statement and it works now "cleanly", and my HTTP requests still execute lambda functions as desired.